# what will happen we don't use @override annotation?

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee, overriding

In Java, if a parent and child class share the same method with the same signature, what would happen if I didn't use the @override annotation in the child class? Would it still compile and execute?

Comment: That annotation is optional - if you don't use it nothing your program can still compile and run successfully.

Comment: Possible Duplicate to [When do you use Java's @Override annotation and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why).